# Make partition B content appears like a folder on partition A

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, symbolic-link

Is it possible using commands in Windows Server 2008 to make some folders on a partition B accessible as if they were on partition A?

Example:

D:\programb(some files)
D:\programa(some files)

should be accessible like this, even by IIS:

C:\allprograms\programa
C:\allprograms\programb

Is that feasible using something like mklink, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's called mklink. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.10).aspx

Edit - to clarify. You have a target folder - the one that already exists and contains your content, one of your examples was D:\programa\ . You want to create a link to it - that link doesn't currently exist, and would be C:\allprograms\programa\ .

mklink /d C:\allprograms\programa\ D:\programa\

That makes a soft link at c:\allprograms\programa (which didn't exist a moment ago) and points to the target d:\programa.

Tip - if you've tried something and it didn't work as expected, then include in your question those details - what you tried (exact syntax please) and the results, including any errors (verbatim.)

Comment: Yes, like mentionned in my post. I tried a bit with the information provided by Microsoft and the result was folders I can't access. I think I just don't understand the principles behind mklink.

Comment: Did my edit help you? Don't forget to mark this answer if it works for you now.

Comment: Just tried. That's crazy, really useful for a streaming website.